# Piping an Ask without blocking parent actor

Tags: akka.net

I want to access a child actor of some parent actor from outside of their hierarchy.  I could use `ActorSelection` and target the path directly, but the child actor might not exist.  Piping the message through its parent means that the parent can safely create and stop the actor as it deems necessary.

The problem I face now is that I am dealing with a I/O-bound **ask** to this child actor. And because this message now pipes through the parent actor, the parent actor is bound by these expensive ask requests, thus blocking it from processing its other messages.

I have the receive handler set up as follows on the parent:

```
Receive<GetThings>(
    message =>
    {
        GetOrCreateChildActor()
            .Ask(message)
            .PipeTo(Sender);
    }
);
```

How can I achieve piping through this ask request without blocking the parent actor?

Answer (score 1):

`Ask` method by itself won't block any actor. All it does is to serve as a converter between actor-style message passing and Task-based completion mechanism.

While your example would work, you don't need to use ask here given this specific example. The simpler solution would be to use `Tell(message, Sender)` or even simpler `Forward(message)` instead of `Ask` - they both will send a message to a child actor specifying current `Sender` as a sender of that message (instead of parent).